# Extending sentenceAnnotator from Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to extend the SentenceAnnotator abstract class. But I am facing issues with trying to override two methods - requirementsSatisfied() and requires(). I have looked at many examples of classes extending SentenceAnnotator and most of them have the same signature.

```
@Override
public Set<Class<? extends CoreAnnotation>> requirementsSatisfied() { return Collections.EMPTY_SET; }
@Override
public Set<Class<? extends CoreAnnotation>> requires() { return Collections.EMPTY_SET; }
```

I am getting an error with this on Eclipse.

Multiple markers at this line

- CoreAnnotation is a raw type. References to generic type CoreAnnotation should be parameterized
- The return type is incompatible with Annotator.requirementsSatisfied()
- implements edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotator.requirementsSatisfied

I am unable to resolve the error. What makes it worse is that Eclipse suggests a change which actually doesn't change anything. How should I override the two methods?

Answer (score 1):

just clean build your project and run it. it should work

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But why is Eclipse-level Java interpretor declaring this as an `Error`?

Comment: This is something strange, I have the same problem on a project when import it with Eclipse but not if I import it with IntelliJ...

Comment: I don't know, it's really strange